# Не отправляются стикеры telebot

Tags: python, telebot

начал создавать бота для тг, но почему-то не получается отправлять стикеры после первого сообщения.. я знаю что это скорее всего какая-то идиотская ошибка, но  все же..

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token='token')

@bot.message_handler(content_types= ['text'])
def text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello!) Let me show it ' +emoji_id_kiss + emoji_id_redheart)

@bot.send_sticker("message.chat.id", 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAECvythF-HdcnawXpSl40T53qEtuiwf6wAC0wADVp29CvUyj5fVEvk9IAQ')
#CAACAgIAAxkBAAECvythF-HdcnawXpSl40T53qEtuiwf6wAC0wADVp29CvUyj5fVEvk9IAQ
emoji_id_redheart = '\U00002764'
emoji_id_kiss ='\U0001F61A'

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=1)
```

Comment: Обязателен ли '@' перед отправкой стикера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text(message):
    if message.text == 'sticker':
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAADAgADsQADWQMDAAEJK1niI56hlhYE')
```

Если пользователь боту пришлёт слово «sticker» то в ответ мы отправим ему свой стикер. За место send_message вызывается метод send_sticker также передаётся id и за место текста отправляется ID стикера. Все просто — стикер отправлен

Для того что бы отправить стикер из бота, нам нужно узнать ID нужного нам стикера. Сделать это просто, отправьте любой стикер боту «@StickerID_Bot» и он в ответ вернёт Вам ID файла

Comment: Спасибо, помогло :)

Comment: @Alymor Поставишь голос вверх, если помог?)